# Intuition behind categorical cross entropy

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, cross-entropy

I'm trying to make categorical cross entropy loss function to better understand intuition behind it.
So far my implementation looks like this:

```py
# Observations
y_true = np.array([[0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1]])
y_pred = np.array([[0.05, 0.95, 0.05], [0.1, 0.8, 0.1]])

# Loss calculations
def categorical_loss():
  loss1 = -(0.0 * np.log(0.05) + 1.0 * np.log(0.95) + 0 * np.log(0.05))
  loss2 = -(0.0 * np.log(0.1) + 0.0 * np.log(0.8) + 1.0 * np.log(0.1))
  loss = (loss1 + loss2) / 2 # divided by 2 because y_true and y_pred have 2 observations and 3 classes
  return loss

# Show loss
print(categorical_loss()) # 1.176939193690798
```

However I do not understand how function should behave to return correct value when:

- at least one number from `y_pred` is `0` or `1` because then `log` function returns `-inf` or `0` and how code implementation should look like in this case
- at least one number from `y_true` is `0` because multiplication by `0` always returns `0` and value of `np.log(0.95)` will be discarded then and how code implementation should look like in this case as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding `y_pred` being 0 or 1, digging into the Keras backend source code for both [`binary_crossentropy`](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/985521ee7050df39f9c06f53b54e17927bd1e6ea/keras/backend/numpy_backend.py#L325) and [`categorical_crossentropy`](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/985521ee7050df39f9c06f53b54e17927bd1e6ea/keras/backend/numpy_backend.py#L333), we get:

```
def binary_crossentropy(target, output, from_logits=False):
    if not from_logits:
        output = np.clip(output, 1e-7, 1 - 1e-7)
        output = np.log(output / (1 - output))
    return (target * -np.log(sigmoid(output)) +
            (1 - target) * -np.log(1 - sigmoid(output)))


def categorical_crossentropy(target, output, from_logits=False):
    if from_logits:
        output = softmax(output)
    else:
        output /= output.sum(axis=-1, keepdims=True)
    output = np.clip(output, 1e-7, 1 - 1e-7)
    return np.sum(target * -np.log(output), axis=-1, keepdims=False)
```

from where you can clearly see that, in both functions, there is a **clipping** operation of the `output` (i.e. predictions), in order to avoid infinities from the logarithms:

```
output = np.clip(output, 1e-7, 1 - 1e-7)
```

So, here `y_pred` will never be exactly 0 or 1 in the underlying calculations. The handling is similar in other frameworks.

Regarding `y_true` being 0, there is not any issue involved - the respective terms are set to 0, as they should be according to the mathematical definition.